# Godot shader rendering differently on android than in the editor

Tags: shader, gdscript, godot4

Using Godot4 and targeting android devices.

I'm still very much a beginner in the world of graphics rendering, so I apologize if the issue is obvious.

I applied a simple blur shader to a colorRect that fills the entire screen in my android app. It works perfectly in the editor, but when I export the app to android, instead of blurring the screen, changing the 'lod' variable appears to make the screen a solid yellow color.

I've tried both the "Mobile" and "Compatibility" renderers and got the same result.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Thank you.

Here's the shader script:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D SCREEN_TEXTURE : hint_screen_texture, filter_linear_mipmap;
uniform float lod: hint_range(0.0, 5) = 0.0;

void fragment(){
    vec4 color = textureLod(SCREEN_TEXTURE, SCREEN_UV, lod);
    COLOR = color;
}
```